# Hazelcast stuck in TIMED_WAITING when using 2nd-level cache

Tags: hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast 3.2.6 as second level cache for Hibernate. The cluster has 4 servers with multiple Read/Update/Delete operations being performed on the DB. It was running fine for quite sometime suddenly I see that all the threads which are trying to perform db operation are stuck, following is an extract from thread dump, there are no exceptions being printed.

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.pollResponse(BasicInvocation.java:767)
    - locked &lt;0x0000000665956110&gt; (a com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.waitForResponse(BasicInvocation.java:719)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:697)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:676)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.getSafely(BasicInvocation.java:689)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxySupport.lock(LockProxySupport.java:80)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxySupport.lock(LockProxySupport.java:74)
    at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxy.lock(LockProxy.java:70)
    at com.xxx.database.ccsecure.persistance.impl.DataStore.get(DataStore.java:120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the invocation doesn't get a result. This means that the invocation-future is not going to complete. The big question is: why does the operation not get a response to its request.

Do you know which operation it is?